# java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result without while loop

Tags: java, servlets

i am creating simple edit page , and getting this error :`java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set`. i did my research , there are bunch of question with same error , (they were having some problems for not using rs.next() in looping ) .i am not even using loop so couldn't find anything helpful.

there's not much to explain here's the code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*; 
    import java.sql.*;

    public class Edit1 extends HttpServlet {  
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   
               throws ServletException, IOException {  
              
                  response.setContentType("text/html");  
                  PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();   

                  String sid=request.getParameter("id");  
                  int id=Integer.parseInt(sid); 
    
    try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/store", "root", "");
         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id="+id);
 
         String name = rs.getString("name");  
         double price = rs.getDouble("price");
         int quantity = rs.getInt("quantity");
             
            out.print("<form action='Edit2' method='post'>");  
            out.print("<table>");  
            out.print("<tr><td></td><td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='"+id+"'/></td></tr>");  
            out.print("<tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type='text' name='name' value='"+name+"'/></td></tr>");  
            out.print("<tr><td>Price:</td><td><input type='number' name='price' value='"+price+"'/></td></tr>");  
            out.print("<tr><td>Quantity:</td><td><input type='number' name='quantity' value='"+quantity+"'/></td></tr>");  
            out.print("<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Save'/></td></tr>");  
            out.print("</table>");  
            out.print("</form>");  

            out.close(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Not even printing stack tracks.

Comment: You are also not using `rs.next()`.

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks. i used rs.next() right after query line , and it worked but still i don't understand why? what i know is we use rs.next() to move to next row while we are using loop.but i am having only single record here. ain't i pointing to it already? why do i have to move to next?

Comment: After `executeQuery` the cursor is still before the first row.